# two ng-model with the same value on a form

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, angular-ngmodel

I have a simple form with two text inputs like below:

```
<form>
    // this is visible in mobile view
    <input id="mobileView" type="email" required ng-model="myValue" />

    // this is visible on desktop view
    <input id="desktopView" type="email" required ng-model="myValue" />
</form>
```

my question is does doing so violate angular form validation? because both of the inputs are in DOM and in one view one of them have value and in other view it doesn't have any value. does this break angular's validation?

Comment: No problem with your code, it's okay.

Comment: @SasankSunkavalli ng-hide/ng-show only add/remove style `display:none` so it won't help here because both input will be registered in this form. You should use `ng-if` if you would like to register `input` depending on the view.

Comment: @krutkowski86 Thanks for the information

Comment: @krutkowski86 the problem is that I don't want to use `ng-if`, it is all handled with styles.

Comment: @HadiAmiri so you'll have problems with overall form validation, because you'll have errors on hidden input's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct and  use ng-if it handle the DOM elements.

```
<form>
    // this is visible in mobile view
    <input id="mobileView" type="email" ng-if="condition for mobile view" required ng-model="myValue" />

    // this is visible on desktop view
    <input id="desktopView" type="email" ng-if="condition for desktop view" required ng-model="myValue" />
</form>
```